# Tricky bug with DataTable/Datasource autoincrement column syncing when deleting rows

Tags: c#, mysql, concurrency, datatable, dataadapter

I posted this question a few days ago but made a hash of explaining the issue properly, so hopefully this attempt is clearer. I have run across a DBConcurrency error when attempting to use the C# MySQLDataAdapter.Update() function on my Datasource, which is a MYSQL database.

The source of the DataTable I am manipulating in my C# program is a table in the database which i extracted using the MySQLDataAdapter. I want to manipulate rows, then use the Update() function of the DataAdapter to save the changes to the database. It works well for the most part, but I have discovered one difficult to solve problem involving autoincremented columns.

Lets say the database table has a list of records like:

```
1 Apple
2 Orange
3 Banana
4 Pear
```

Where the first ID column is autoincremented. I can fill a DataTable just fine and have it autoincrement by using MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey() and so on, and if I add a new record "Grapes" to the DataTable the autoincrement ID column will be 5 and the database will accept it when I run Update() on it.

However, If I add the Grapes record to the DataTable, then delete it, and then add it again (implausible I know, but it happens), the DataTable autoincrement just keeps ticking up, so now it looks like this:

```
1 Apple
2 Orange
3 Banana
4 Pear
6 Grapes
```

And if i run the Update() now, the "Grapes" record auto ID gets saved into the DATABASE table as 5, because that's where the database autoincrement is at, but in the DataTable it's listed as 6, so they're now out of sync and if I delete the Grapes row from the DataTable and run Update() again, I get the error:

```
"Concurrency violation: the DeleteCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records."
```

on the Update() line of my program.

I've looked around and it seems like this sort of de-syncing can happen fairly regularly, but at this stage I'm wondering if there's anything I can do about it without going back and tearing up most of the code I've written.

Comment: Add your own delete command / procedure  and put an if exists in it, or detect that the record you are deleting hasn't been posted and cancel the insert instead.

Comment: The issue isn't that the record I'm trying to delete doesn't exist though, the issue is that the record I'm trying to delete has the autoID 6 (for example) in the DataTable, but autoID 5 in the database table, so the delete command is looking for autoID 6 in the database and not finding it (I think?)

Comment: you said you added it then deleted it then added again... Unless you commit each change and refresh, exclusive lock the table, or use GetChanges and reconcile, this is never going to work. The id of inserted records can't possibly be in step with the underlying sql table, it's disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I have been able to get around this is to do the following:

```
DataTable copyTable = Table.Copy();
Table.Clear();

for( int i = 0; i < copyTable.Rows.Count; i++ )
 {
      DataRow r = copyTable.Rows[i];
      r[0] = i;
      Table.ImportRow( r );
 }
```

In effect after I delete a row I copy the table to a temporary table, then loop through the remaining rows, set my "ID" column (r[0]) using the count of the rows.